# Is there any way to implement a "Msgbox" into this code after the case result?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below has a `Select case RandomNumber` and has a result if it's correct and a result if it's not correct. I want to add a MsgBox (that appears after the result) which says "you won" or "you lost".

I am making a roulette table as a project in excel using VBA.

Here is what I've tried as well as searching a lot but no results.

```
Case 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36
    Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2 **And Msgbox "you won"**
Case Else
    Balance = Balance - PlayerBet **And Msgbox "you lost"**
```

---

```
Sub Column_bet_1st()
    'Column bet 2:1'
     Dim PlayerBet As Range, Balance As Range, Bet_input As Range, RandomNumber As Integer

     Set PlayerBet = Range("O21")
     Set Balance = Range("L18")
     Set Bet_input = Range("O18")

     RandomNumber = Cells(1, 1)

     If Bet_input = "Column 1" Then
         Select Case RandomNumber
             Case 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36
                 Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2 
             Case Else
                 Balance = Balance - PlayerBet 
         End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

The expected result is that after the Case is either true or false a MsgBox will pop up on the screen with whatever i'd like to write in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right

```
Sub Column_bet_1st()

'Column bet 2:1'

Dim PlayerBet As Range, Balance As Range, Bet_input As Range, RandomNumber As Integer

    Set PlayerBet = Range("O21")

    Set Balance = Range("L18")

    Set Bet_input = Range("O18")

    RandomNumber = Cells(1, 1)

    If Bet_input = "Column 1" Then
        Select Case RandomNumber
        Case 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36
            MsgBox "You won", vbOKOnly, "Win"
            Balance = Balance + PlayerBet * 2
        Case Else
            Balance = Balance - PlayerBet
            MsgBox "You lost", vbOKOnly, "Lose"
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```